# Focus on blackberry touch devices

Tags: javascript, blackberry, cordova

I recently designed an app for blackberry with phonegap it works fine except for one issue. The issue is that when i tap outside the form fields(input, submit etc) focus leaves the interface. i want the focus to always be on one of the form fields like in the login page for Facebook app and Twitter app. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use set focus()   properties.Like that
 document.getElementById("Textbox1").focus();

Comment: i'm actually quite new to all this could you please explain a bit further. thanks

Comment: If you have like Button have ID ="btn" then write this  document.getElementById("btn").focus(); in body region.